# when copy html form with checkbox the checked not copied

Tags: html, checkbox

I check the checkboxes and copied the form to clipboard, then paste to excel, the checkboxes are unchecked!
how can I copy the value as it is at the form?
Thanks in advance!

```html
<form>
    <div id="container">
       <input type="checkbox" name="chk"  />Checkbox1<br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="chk" /> Checkbox2 <br />
    </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: There’s a difference between the `checked` attribute and the `checked` property. None of your `<input>`s have the `checked` attribute, so you can’t really expect a cloned or copied element to still be checked. You could try (un-)setting the `checked` attribute when (un-)checking the checkbox with something like `addEventListener("change", ({target}) => { if(target.matches("[type='checkbox']")){ target.toggleAttribute("checked", target.checked); } });` in JS (possibly using the [`toggleAttribute` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute#Polyfill)).

Comment: thanks a lot  Xufox!! I now use ng-checked="expression" instead of ng-model="expression" and that do the trick to add the checked attribute

Answer (score 0):

I now use angularJS to check the CB by ng-checked="expression" instead of ng-model="expression" and that do the trick to add the checked attributeת as Xufox Lit my eyes